# Uncertain behaviour of jQuery html()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am using **jQuery 1.11.1**. I've upgraded it from 1.6.1.1. To upgrade jQuery I've followed [jQuery upgrade guide](https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/), as so many important changes been introduced from version 1.9.0. I've put **jQuery migrate version 1.2.1** in resource path.

Recently I came across an issue where jQuery does not *'set'* html content. I've quoted *'set'* because when I alert `(jquery_selector).html()` then it shows proper content value, but when I check that selector element using browser's inspect element feature, it does not have that content. Here is code snippet:

```
try {
    widget.element.empty().html(data);
    // document.getElementById(widget.element.prop("id")).innerHTML = data;
    // alert("HTML Content set: " + widget.element.html());
    widget.element.fadeIn('fast');
} catch (ex) {
    alert("Exception in setting and fadeIn()" + ex);
}
```

Here `data` is html content received using Ajax request. Data received properly with status code `200`.

In either case (jquery html() or innerHTML) of setting content, alert of element's html() gives same result as `data`.

No error or exception observed during executing this code.

Can anyone guide me where I am making mistake? Or am I missing any step while upgrading jQuery?

Javascript file:

```
var ajaxPanel = {
    options:{
        opened:false,
        triggerEvent:'click'
    },

    _init:function () {
        var widget = this;
        $(document).on(widget.options.triggerEvent, this.options.trigger, function () {
            if (widget.options.triggerValue) {
                if ($(this).val() == widget.options.triggerValue) {
                    try {
                    widget.show();
                    }catch (ex) {
                        alert(ex);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    widget.hide();
                }
            }
            else {
                widget.show();
            }
        });
    },

    show:function () {
        var widget = this;
        var options = this.options;
        if (options.opened) {
            return;
        }
        $.ajax({
            url:options.contentUrl,
            success:function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
                if (checkLoginTimeout(xhr)) {
                    return;
                }
                if (options.group && !options.triggerValue) {
                    $("." + options.group).bssAjaxPanel('hide');
                }
                options.opened = true;
                widget.element.empty().html(data);
                widget.element.fadeIn('fast');
            },
            error:function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                if (!ajaxErrorHandle(jqXHR)) {
                    widget.showErrors(errorThrown);
                }
            },
            cache:false
        });
    },

    hide:function () {
        if (!this.options.opened) {
            return;
        }
        var widget = this;
        this.options.opened = false;
        this.element.hide();
        this.element.empty();
    }
}

$.widget("ui.ajaxPanel", ajaxPanel);
```

Javascript widget call:

```
<input type="radio" name="messageType" value="1" id="mail" />
<label>Message Type Mail</label>
<div id="mailPanel" style="display: none;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function(){$('#mailPanel').ajaxPanel({trigger:'input[name="messageType"]',triggerValue:'1',contentUrl:'<URL_TO_RESOURCE>'})});</script>

<input type="radio" name="messageType" value="2" id="content" />
<label>Message Type Content</label>
<div id="contentPanel" style="display: none;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function(){$('#contentPanel').ajaxPanel({trigger:'input[name="messageType"]',triggerValue:'2',contentUrl:'<URL_TO_RESOURCE>'})});</script>
```

Comment: Since you're replacing the content with `html()`, why do you use `empty()` before that? And are you sure you're changing the correct element?

Comment: Can you inspect the element before updating the data, because to me it appear that you didn't find the element properly (anymore).

Comment: `In either case (jquery html() or innerHTML) of setting content, alert of element's html() gives same result as data.` __What is the problem?__ Not able to find element using browser's inspect element feature is completely your mistake nothing to do with jQuery.

Comment: try to write a html snippet also to get proper answer.I think the selector that you are using is wrong paste in here your complete code snippet.

Comment: Yes, I am sure that it is changing correct element. And this code was working perfectly fine with jQuery 1.6.1.1. This issue observed after I've upgraded to jQuery 1.11.1.

Comment: @Satpal Here by setting content, I mean that alert gives same result as `data`. But that content is not been displayed on browser, neither it is set on browser's inspect element.